# DB error: Already Exists

Tags: error

Using Civi 5.20.3
Contacts are getting an error (DB error: Already Exists) when filling out a profile form. 
This is what I saw on the Drupal Watchdog. What does it mean?

$Fatal Error Details = Array ( [callback] => Array ( [0] => CRM_Core_Error [1] => handle ) [code] => -5 [message] => DB Error: already exists [mode] => 16 [debug_info] => UPDATE civicrm_cache SET data = .....

created_date = FROM_UNIXTIME(1581961411), expired_date = FROM_UNIXTIME(1581983012) WHERE group_name = "contact-20fields" AND path = "exportableFields All_0_0_0_" [nativecode=1062 ** Duplicate entry 'contact-20fields-exportableFields All_0_0_0_-2020-02-17 11:43:31' for key 'UI_group_path_date'] [type] => DB_Error [user_info] => UPDATE civicrm_cache SET data

Comment: For what it's worth, this still happens:
    [code] => -5
    [message] => DB Error: already exists
    [mode] => 16
    [debug_info] => UPDATE civicrm_cache SET data = '[SOME DATA HERE]', created_date = FROM_UNIXTIME(1612723665), expired_date = FROM_UNIXTIME(1612745265) WHERE group_name = "contact-20fields" AND path = "custom importableFields 49f393f8cc6aed05fdb0b39c686d1d28" [nativecode=1062 ** Duplicate entry 'contact-20fields-custom importableFields 49f393f8cc6aed05fdb0...' for key 'UI_group_path_date']

This bricked the whole system until cache clear.

Comment: Got burned by this today :)

Answer (score 1):

While it's hard to tell without the entire error message it looks like given that the query appears to be an update to a cache table I'd recommend clearing your caches.

drush cc all or via /civicrm/admin/setting/updateConfigBackend?reset=1

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me on a website with Drupal and CiviCRM. I had no access to drush. I have done a truncate of the civicrm_cache table, and it has been enough to solve the problem.